# How to separate licensing code into Layers? One for validation and other for License Creation

Tags: oop, design-patterns, licensing

I am working on a licensing architecture for my internal projects. (No space for the additional cost of Gemalto). My License manager will have two responsibilities,

1. Read from file and Validate the License (to be used in the
   applications that I create)
2. Generate a license file with the information supplied (will stay with me as an internal tool)

Now Part 1 and 2 are going to depend on the same encryption-decryption and serialization-deserialization logic.

```
public interface ILicenseManager
{
    License ValidateAndGetLicense();
    void CreateLicense(License license);
}
```

I need here to structure my license manager class in such a way that only code needed for Part 1 (i.e. decryption and reading) gets shipped to the customer. Another part always remains with me.

The aim here is not to repeat code. Depend on the same logic.
Is there any standard way of doing it or any design principal that handles this situation.

I have considered using ISP (interface segregation principal) and Proxy pattern.
But still, both will need the whole assembly to be shipped. Another option is to separate the logic and write them in separate assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

I would not worry about the code, i.e. the "encryption" getting shipped to the client, it's not important. The important part is that you keep the *private key* used to generate valid licenses, and ship your *public key* with your application.

So, if your reasons for wanting to separate the encryption from the decryption is "security", I think that is covered well enough by you keeping your private key secret.

That being said, from the point of view of object-orientation, I would model the problem differently. The core of your problem is the `License`, which would need to validate itself at a given moment in time, so:

```java
public interface License {
    boolean validNow(); // Or whatever you need
}
```

Then just create an implementation that reads from a file:

```java
public final class FileLicense {
    ...
}
```

So at this point, you can read and validate licenses from a file.

Ok, so how to "create" a `License`. The easy way (which, depending on your requirements may or may not be a good fit), is to just create another implementation, like this:

```java
public final class NewLicense {
    ...
    public NewLicense(PrivateKey companyKey, license data...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this design, you basically just always implement an interface, and still can separate the creation and usage of licenses. You can also put the store/load from file functionality directly into the `License` class if you only need file-based licenses for now (KISS, YAGNI).

Comment: Thanks for the private key part. Rest of my code is close to the suggestion you gave, Except that the license manager is doing validation and License class more of a Anaemic model only responsible for holding data and serialization-deserialization logic. I am letting the LicenseManager class validate the license so that it can use different validation parameters if business case changes, without having a risk of losing backward compatibility.